# How to add a subview to a UINavigation Controller without losing navigation bar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a SplitViewController which has two UITableViewControllers - one master/root one detail. Everything works swimmingly.

I have a UIView which is shown on the detail view controller before the user selects an item in the root view controller. It's set up like this:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:makeSentenceHelperView];
[self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:makeSentenceHelperView];
```

The detailViewController is set up like so:

```
UINavigationController *detailNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];
```

Where `detailViewController` is a subclass of UITableView.

The problem is that this subView hides the buttons and navigation bar from the detail view controller's navigation bar - which is a problem when you launch the SVC in portrait mode (there's no way to select a root item with the root popup).

[image]

How can I present the view inside the navigation controller, so that the navigation bar and buttons appear in the detail view?

Comment: Why don't you just display the details of the first item in master view by default?

Comment: Because when users first start using the app their won't be anything in the tables - I want to show them how to easily get started.

Comment: Then why not consider using guide to the app kind of thing just like Pulse news and many other apps do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for my intended users I think that this way will work best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I added a UINavigationController to my helper UIView, and added a UIButtonBarItem to call the popover for selecting a new item in the master view. It seems really simple in retrospect. The only tricky bit will be making the UIButtonBarItem hide when in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make `detailViewController` a subclass of UIView, instead go with UIViewController. So your `splitView` array will contain a instance of `UINavigationController`(rootVC) and other of `UIViewController` (detailVC).

Add a toolbar on the top of  `detailViewController` and in landscape mode left side will be covered by your UITableView of `rootVC` and you will be able to see toolbar where you can add some button to its right side (will probably serve as navigation bar..:) . Rest of the things can be handled by `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`.